# What about the many addresses unpresented in the /proc/$pid/maps file?

Tags: linux, paging, virtual-memory

**Brief Version**:
what status are the addresses unpresented in the maps file? Are they belongs to unallocated virtual pages or allocated from anonymous file or others?

**Detailed Version**
I'm learning about VM. In my book(CS:APP), I learned that all virtual pages can be cut into three sets: unallocated, allocated but not cached, allocated and cached.I have some questions about "what are allocated pages and unallocated pages? When are pages allocated?" And also, is stack and heap belongs to allocated pages or unallocated or only allocate when used?
Trying to solve these problems, I read the /proc/$pid/maps file, while I think I can get anything I want from it. In my mind, the file contains all memory mapping relations. But there isn't information about is it cached(I know maybe it cannot be seen from user mode...), and are the unpresented pages unallocated?

Comment: I'm not sure of your book's terminology, but address regions not listed in the maps file are simply *unmapped*.  Those pages are marked "not present" in the page tables.  If the process should access such a page, a page fault will occur; the kernel will not access or  allocate any physical memory in response, but will simply deliver a SIGSEGV signal, normally killing the process (i.e. a segfault).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I don't really know about the maps file. What I do know is that the information on every page is stored in `page` structures at all time. I'm gonna take x86-64 as an example.

For x86-64 on Linux you have Page Global Directory (PGD), Page Upper Directory (PUD), Page Middle Directory (PMD) and Page Directory (PD). The address of the bottom of the PGD table is stored in the CR3 register. PGD contains addresses of the PUDs, PUDs contain addresses of the PMDs, PMDs contain addresses of the PDs and PDs contain addresses of the physical pages.

A virtual address, of which only 48 bits are used, is split into 5 parts. The 12 least significant bits are the offset in the physical page. The next chunk of 9 bits is the offset in the PD. The next chunk is the offset in PMD etc. For example let's say you have virtual address `0x0000000000000123`. This virtual address will be translated by the MMU in the CPU by looking at entry (offset) 0 of the PGD, entry 0 of the PUD, entry 0 of the PMD, entry 0 of the PD and finally offset 0x123 in the actual physical page in RAM. Every virtual address is 64 bits of which only the 48 least significant bits will be used.

At boot, the kernel makes checks to determine how much memory is available. It then builds its kernel structures accordingly.

When the kernel boots it will mark all pages as unallocated in its own structures (except for kernel needs). The `page` structure is important for this. The kernel has a `page` C structure for every page in the system (https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/memory_mapping.html and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/include/linux/mm_types.h). This structure informs the kernel whether the page is allocated or not.

> Each physical page in the system has a struct page associated with
> it to keep track of whatever it is we are using the page for at the
> moment. Note that we have no way to track which tasks are using
> a page, though if it is a pagecache page, rmap structures can tell us
> who is mapping it.

At first the pages are mostly unallocated. When you start a new process by launching an executable as the user of the system, pages are allocated for your process. On Linux, executables are ELF files. ELF is a conventional format which separates code in loadable segments. Each segment gets a virtual address at which it is going to be loaded in the virtual address space.

Let's say you have an elf file with one segment which should be loaded at virtual address 0x400000. When you launch that ELF executable, the Linux kernel will call certain functions which will look at the size of the code and allocate pages accordingly. The kernel will look at its structures and determine using algorithms where the process will be allocated in RAM. It will then setup the page tables according to where the virtual addresses for that process should land in actual physical memory.

What's important to understand is that each CPU core in the system has only one process running at a time. Each core has it's own set of page tables. When a process switch occurs for one core, the page tables are swapped completely to point to somewhere else in RAM. The same virtual address can point anywhere in RAM depending on how the page tables are set up.

The kernel holds a task_struct for every process running in the system. The task_struct contains a field named pgd which is a pointer to the PGD of the process. Each process has its very own PGD. If you dereference the pointer to the PGD you get the actual value of the first entry of the PGD. This first entry is the address of the PUD. With this only pointer, the kernel can reach every table belonging to the process and modify them at will.

While a process is running, it can ask for more memory. This is called dynamic memory allocation. The kernel has no way to know how much memory the process is going to ask in advance since it is dynamic (done while code is executing). When the process asks for more memory, the kernel determines what page to give to the process depending on an algorithm. It then marks this page as allocated to that process. The task_struct contains a mm field which is of type mm_struct (https://manybutfinite.com/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/). It is a memory descriptor for that process so that the kernel can know what memory the process is using. In itself the process doesn't need that information since the process should rely only on itself to ask for memory properly to the operating system and to not jump somewhere in RAM where it doesn't belong.

You ask about heap and stack. The stack for a process is allocated at the beginning of the process and I think it has a fixed size. If you overflow the stack, you will throw a CPU exception which will prompt the kernel to kill your process. Each CPU core has a special register called RSP. This is the stack pointer. It points to the top of the stack (the stack grows downward toward low memory). When the kernel allocates a stack for a process you launch, it will set up this register to point at the top of it. The stack pointer contains a virtual address. It will thus be translated using the page tables just like any address.

The heap is allocated and managed completely by the OS. It doesn't have special registers like the stack. It is allocated only when the process asks for more memory during code execution. The kernel knows in advance how much memory a process requires. It is all written in the ELF executable. All static memory is allocated during compilation and thus the kernel knows everything about the size of static memory. The only moment it requires to allocate new memory to a process is when the process actually asks for it. In C++ you use the keyword `new` to ask for heap memory dynamically. If you don't use this keyword, then the kernel knows in advance where your variables will be allocated (where they will be in memory). Only the stack will be used by static memory.